# Recover from horrendous pip/pip3 mess on OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I just wanted to install the lang package.
The problem here is that I have spent ages installing countless packages and don't want to do it all again. I'm no great expert at python package management and I'd rather not need to become one. This happened because I cut and pasted an answer from Stack Overflow in the naive hope that it was actually correct (see below).

Is there a way to simply remove the pip installation and keep the installed package information and then re-install pip3 again using the old package info?

I imagine that pip must keep the package info in some database, so possibly I can copy that out, re-install a fresh pip and then copy back the package data?

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** pip3 install lang

```
    Collecting lang
      Downloading lang-1.0.5.tar.gz (5.7 kB)
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/01/gll908b94ll0m5mzltylkp4w0000gn/T/pip-install-y291uctu/lang/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/01/gll908b94ll0m5mzltylkp4w0000gn/T/pip-install-y291uctu/lang/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/01/gll908b94ll0m5mzltylkp4w0000gn/T/pip-install-y291uctu/lang/pip-egg-info
             cwd: /private/var/folders/01/gll908b94ll0m5mzltylkp4w0000gn/T/pip-install-y291uctu/lang/
        Complete output (7 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/private/var/folders/01/gll908b94ll0m5mzltylkp4w0000gn/T/pip-install-y291uctu/lang/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
            with open(path.join(here, '..', 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
          File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 905, in open
            file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/01/gll908b94ll0m5mzltylkp4w0000gn/T/pip-install-y291uctu/lang/../README.md'
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

(That's weird how am I supposed to fix that? Maybe pip is out of date? I don't remember the upgrade command so I'll just get it from Stack Overflow.)

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip

(It's totally not obvious that it's not going to upgrade the right version of pip and that's going to break everything.)

```
    Password:
    Collecting pip
      Downloading pip-20.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 1.7 MB/s 
    Installing collected packages: pip
      Attempting uninstall: pip
        Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
        Uninstalling pip-20.0.2:
          Successfully uninstalled pip-20.0.2
    Successfully installed pip-20.2.2
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip3

(Maybe it's supposed to be pip3 that should have been upgraded here?)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
        ws.require(__requires__)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 20.2.2 (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.0.2'))
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3255, in <module>
        def _initialize_master_working_set():
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3238, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3267, in _initialize_master_working_set
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 586, in _build_master
        return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 599, in _build_from_requirements
        dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** pip3 install lang

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
        ws.require(__requires__)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 20.2.2 (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.0.2'))
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3255, in <module>
        def _initialize_master_working_set():
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3238, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3267, in _initialize_master_working_set
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 586, in _build_master
        return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 599, in _build_from_requirements
        dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** which pip

```
    /usr/local/bin/pip
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** sudo pip uninstall pip

(Perhaps getting rid of the bogus version of pip would help?)

```
    WARNING: The directory '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    Found existing installation: pip 20.2.2
    Uninstalling pip-20.2.2:
      Would remove:
        /usr/local/bin/pip
        /usr/local/bin/pip3
        /usr/local/bin/pip3.8
        /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-20.2.2.dist-info/*
        /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/*
    Proceed (y/n)? y
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.2
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** pip3

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3255, in <module>
        def _initialize_master_working_set():
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3238, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3267, in _initialize_master_working_set
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
        ws.require(__requires__)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** which pip3

```
    /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** pip

```
    zsh: command not found: pip
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** which python3

```
    /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** pip3 uninstall pip3

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3255, in <module>
        def _initialize_master_working_set():
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3238, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3267, in _initialize_master_working_set
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
        ws.require(__requires__)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** find / -name pip 2>/dev/null

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/bin/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/libexec/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/libexec/pip/build/lib/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/libexec/pip/src/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/libexec/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/libexec/pip/src/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/share/doc/python3.7/examples/Tools/msi/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/libexec/bin/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/libexec/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/libexec/pip/build/lib/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/libexec/pip/src/pip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/share/doc/python3.8/examples/Tools/msi/pip
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.2.2-py2.7.egg/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/bin/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/libexec/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/libexec/pip/build/lib/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/libexec/pip/src/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/libexec/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/libexec/pip/src/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/share/doc/python3.7/examples/Tools/msi/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/libexec/bin/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/libexec/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/libexec/pip/build/lib/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/libexec/pip/src/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/share/doc/python3.8/examples/Tools/msi/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.2.2-py2.7.egg/pip
    /System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
    /Users/robotbugs/Library/Caches/pip
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
```

**~/Dropbox/Projects/FileSorting/ScreenShotSorter $** echo "What the f__k\!"

(What's with all these python versions - I thought I was using 3.8?)

```
    What the f__k!
```

Comment: Time to install conda or miniconda!

Comment: "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application"

Comment: @Alrl, any virtual environment will do (though it would have been easier to use one from the beginning). Anaconda isn't necessary.

Comment: This looks like a packaging bug in the `lang` package. With all the crazy damage you've done after that, I'm tempted to suggest a system reinstall.

Comment: @tripleee thats pretty funny if it wasn't so true :)

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: It seems like using get-pip and installing pip 20.2.2 (which puts it in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)) seems to fix it, but I still cant install lang, and im not sure what happened to pip3 which is in /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3 but doenst run, but pip in /usr/local/bin/pip seems to work, and sees the previously installed packages.